# Checking a maven project's repository portability

Tags: java, dependencies, repository, maven

Is there any way to check all dependencies are downloadable from at least one listed repository?

I was once omitted a required repository from my pom.xml.
But maven didn't complain because those dependencies already had been installed in my local repository (~/.m2/repository).

That could be a problem for CI or on another fresh machine.

So I currently using a shell script which removes all dependencies from ~/.m2 and build maven.

Say...

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/{my/required/dependencies/group}
maven clean compile
```

I don't think this is a smart way but it works. :)

Do I have to make a plugin by myself for that?

Comment: Never mind. I found [dependency:purge-local-repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) :)

Comment: Actually you should answer your own question. Then you can pick it as the answer and people can vote on it. Quite helpful actually.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did but they said I can accept my own answer in 2 days. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering for my own question as Chris advised. Thanks.

I (and any of you) can do this with maven-dependency-plugin.
[dependency:purge-local-repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html)